# vmstat and column

Tags: bash, formatting

I want to use column utility to format output of iostat in aligned columns.

I want to run something like:

```
vmstat 1 10 | column -t
```

But the output appers only after 10 sec (vmstat completes its work) and not each second.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13):

try this:

```
vmstat -w 1 5
```

this works fine in vm, but when in physic machine which has large memory the columu of cpu maybe not looks as better as in vm.

Answer (score 3):

The reason this happens is that column waits to gather as much input as possible on which to base its column guesses. It has no way of knowing that the data pattern repeats every second.

You can approximate what you want to do by running this:

```
for i in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9; do iostat | column -t; sleep 1; done
```

---

**EDIT**

Thanks to a couple of suggestions from Dennis:

```
for i in {0..9} ; do iostat 1 1 | column -t; sleep 1; done
```

The only difference from the original is that the first header line is repeated every second. Some footwork with `sed` or `grep` could take care of that.

Comment: For vmstat using your proposal you can run: "vmstat | sed -n '1,2p' | column -t; for i in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9; do vmstat | column -t | sed -n '3p';sleep 1; done" which gives similar, but formatted output to "vmstat 1 10". Is there really no way to do it in easy way?

Comment: @idimba: in Bash, you can do `for i in {0..9}`. You can do `vmstat 1 1` in both places.

Comment: @idimba: Sorry, I'm not familiar with the vmstat format so I wasn't aware how you wanted the headers to look. I think Dennis' suggestion makes it pretty simple. I'll edit my answer to reflect our best efforts combined.

Comment: And no, there doesn't seem to be a way of getting `column` to work differently. I think it's simple enough, don't you? Best I can do, in any case. You might try asking the question on superuser.com, they do more of this kinda stuff.

Comment: This formats iostat nicely, but it only shows the first report from iostat (e.g. information since last reboot), while most of us are really looking for "statistics collected during the interval since the previous report". From `man iostat`: _The first report generated by the iostat command provides statistics concerning the time since the system was booted. Each subsequent report covers the  time  since the previous report._

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
vmstat 1 10 >> /tmp/vmout.txt; tail -f /tmp/vmout.txt
```